# ORA-01843: Not a valid month, While using Select Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have three tables following is the table description of tables

```
SQL> DESC DRIVERS12


Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 D_ID                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 DNAME                                              VARCHAR2(30)
 AGE                                                VARCHAR2(30)
 CITY                                               VARCHAR2(30)

SQL> DESC CARS12
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 C_ID                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 COMAPNY                                            VARCHAR2(30)
 MODEL                                              VARCHAR2(30)
 PURCHASE_DATE                                      DATE

SQL> DESC RESERVES12
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 D_ID                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 C_ID                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 DAY                                                VARCHAR2(10)
```

I have taken data in each tables using following syntax:

```
 SQL> INSERT INTO DRIVERS12 VALUES(‘&D_ID’,’&DNAME’,’&AGE’,’&CITY’);
Enter value for d_id: D1
Enter value for dname: P.RAI
Enter value for age: 22
Enter value for city: BENARAS
old   2: VALUES('&D_ID','&DNAME','&AGE','&CITY')
new   2: VALUES('D1','P.RAI','22','BENARAS')

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO CARS12
  2  VALUES('&C_ID','&COMPANY','&MODEL',TO_DATE('&PURCHASE_DATE','DD/MM/YY'));
Enter value for c_id: C1
Enter value for company: ROYAL ENFIELD
Enter value for model: BULLET350
Enter value for purchase_date: 02/10/16
old   2: VALUES('&C_ID','&COMPANY','&MODEL',TO_DATE('&PURCHASE_DATE','DD/MM/YY')
)
new   2: VALUES('C1','ROYAL ENFIELD','BULLET350',TO_DATE('02/10/16','DD/MM/YY'))


1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO RESERVES12
  2  VALUES('&D_DI','&C_ID','&DAY');
Enter value for d_di: D1
Enter value for c_id: C1
Enter value for day: MONDAY
old   2: VALUES('&D_DI','&C_ID','&DAY')
new   2: VALUES('D1','C1','MONDAY')

1 row created.
```

When I try to run the following queries

```
SQL> SELECT C.MODEL,C.COMAPNY,D.CITY
  2  FROM DRIVERS12 D, CARS12 C, RESERVES12 R
  3  WHERE R.D_ID=D.D_ID AND R.C_ID=C.C_ID AND D.DNAME='M.GUHA' AND C.PURCHASE_DATE>'01/01/15';
                                                                                 *
```

I get this error at line 3

```
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

I am using Oracle 10g, Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Date literals are written [like this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've realised the problem is with this part:

```
C.PURCHASE_DATE>'01/01/15'
```

but your fix isn't quite right...

> It was my mistake, when I enter "02/10/16" as input it is getting converted into "02-OCT-16" format.

Your `PURCHASE_DATE` column is a `DATE` as it should be, and a date doesn't have an intrinsic human-readable format - Oracle stores it with its own internal representation. When you query it that is converted to a readable format by your application or client, usually using your session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting - in your case that must be `DD-MON-RR` from the output you got when you queried the table. You can display it in any format you want by calling `TO_CHAR()`, but should leave it as a date for all processing.

The issue is that you're comparing that date value to to a string. Oracle tries to [implicitly convert that string to a date](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-6DB331B5-0F34-4215-9A20-16AEA9D7FF4B), and because the string doesn't match your NLS settings it can't, and throws that error - the same as if you did an explicit conversion with the same format model:

```
select to_date('01/01/2015', 'DD-MON-RR') from dual;

ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

In your answer you are still doing that:

```
C.PURCHASE_DATE>'01-JAN-15'
```

but now the string does match your default format model so the implicit conversion now works, as the equivalent of an explicit `to_date('01-JAN-15', 'DD-MON-RR')`.

But you should not rely on implicit conversions or assume anything about NLS settings. The same query will error if run in a session with a different language (as it relies on `JAN` being an English month abbreviation) or a different `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting. As your column is a date you should explicitly compare it with a date too, using a safer format model (though this still allows for ambiguity between day and month numbers):

```
C.PURCHASE_DATE > TO_DATE('01/01/15', 'DD/MM/RR')
```

or preferably with 4-digit years:

```
C.PURCHASE_DATE > TO_DATE('01/01/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

and with a fixed value you can also use an unambiguous [ANSI date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1):

```
C.PURCHASE_DATE > DATE '2015-01-01'
```

One other observation is that you're looking for records *after* midnight on that date; you might really want to include anything that happened at exactly midnight too:

```
C.PURCHASE_DATE >= DATE '2015-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going wrong here

```
C.PURCHASE_DATE>2015;

2015 is not date format allowed by oracle , replace 2015 to DD/MM/YY instead 
for example 24/02/19
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @nissimabehcera but i have figured out my mistake and posted it into answer section.

Comment: you can also use TO_DATE function of oracle to modify date format as you want

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, when I enter "02/10/16" as input it is getting converted into "02-OCT-16" format. I get to know about this by using

```
SELECT *
```

statement.

So,

```
 SQL> SELECT C.MODEL,C.COMAPNY,D.CITY
  2  FROM DRIVERS12 D, CARS12 C, RESERVES12 R
  3  WHERE R.D_ID=D.D_ID AND R.C_ID=C.C_ID AND D.DNAME='M.GUHA' AND C.PURCHASE_D
ATE>'01-JAN-15';
```

is working like a charm.

Comment: _Don't store your dates as text_.

Comment: I have used TO_DATE('&PURCHASE_DATE','DD/MM/YY')); this format but how it has changed to 01-Jan-15 format? Would you please explain.

Comment: The `PURCHASE_DATE` column *is* as `DATE`, so that's OK (but your insert should really be using 4-digit years). But a date does not have any real format, Oracle stores it in its own representation. When you query it your client formats it or it defaults to your session NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting, so if you want to see a specific format use `TO_CHAR()`. The problem you had though is that you're comparing the date with a string, which is also doing implicit conversion. You should compare it with another date, not a string.